# ExpressJS - throw er Unhandled error event

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I created expressjs application using the following commands:

```
express -e folderName
npm install ejs --save
npm install
```

When I run the application with: `node app.js`, I have the following errors:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:884:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1022:14)
    at listen (net.js:1044:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1110:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (folderName/app.js:33:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: EADDRINUSE means that the port is already in use.  try changing what port the web server in app.js listens on or kill whatever is currently using that port if you don't need it.

Comment: If closing port is not fixing , try this > https://stackoverflow.com/a/52441297/6665568

Answer (score 424, accepted):

You had run another server use the same port like 8080.

Maybe you had run `node app` in other shell, Please close it and run again.

**You can check PORT no. is available or not using**

```
netstat -tulnp | grep <port no>
```

Alternatively, you can use [lsof](https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof):

```
lsof -i :<port no>
```

Comment: I ran in to this using WebStorm. I had two debug sessions open in the same workspace. Doh!

Comment: Such a common error really deserves a better error message.

Comment: This happened to me when using node-activedirectory.  My baseDN was missing the subdomain.  baseDN:'ldap://dc=subdomain,dc=domain,dc=com'

Comment: Was running an instance of `rails server`... :|

Comment: on mac high sierra:   lsof -nP -i4TCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN

Comment: SEE this answer if the above solution is not working  > https://stackoverflow.com/a/52441297/6665568

Comment: thnaks , ur ans not solve my problem but help me to realize the problem

Answer (score 66):

We do get similar error when we sometimes run our express app. We have to follow the same in that case. We need to check if its running in any terminal. 
If you want to find and kill process, follow these steps:

- ps aux | grep node
- Find the process ID (second from the left):
- kill -9 PRCOCESS_ID

*OR*

Use a single command to close all the running node processes.

```
ps aux | awk '/node/{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: `ps aux | grep node | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`

Comment: `killall -r node` (in linux)

Answer (score 37):

An instance is probably still running.
This will fix it.

```
killall node
```

Update: This command will only work on Linux/Ubuntu & Mac.

Comment: killall -9 node

Answer (score 16):

If you're on Linux, this problem can also occur if Nodejs is not running as root.

Change from this:

```
nodejs /path/to/script.js
```

To this:

```
sudo nodejs /path/to/script.js
```

Just happened to me and none of the other suggestions here fixed it.  Luckily I remembered the script was working the other day when running as root.  Hope this helps someone!

**Disclaimer:** This probably isn't the best solution for a production environment.  Starting your service as root may introduce some security holes to your server/application. In my case, this was a solution for a local service, but I'd encourage others to spend some more time trying to isolate the cause.

Comment: Sounds really dangerous to just run the script as root to solve this issue. Unless you are trying to bind to a port under 1024, you should never need to run node as root. I suspect in your case, you are trying to bind to port 80 or 443. I would suggest using Nginx to direct traffic from those ports to nodejs on a higher port, like 8000 or something.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I don't think the particular script I was using called for any of those ports, I'm certainly not using Node as an http server.  Perhaps it was one of the modules I used which called for additional permissions?  I apologize it's been a while so I'm not even sure which script called for this solution.  I'll add a disclaimer about attempting this in a production environment.

Answer (score 13):

This is because the port you are using to run the script is already in use.
You have to stop all other nodes which are using that post.
for that, you can check all node by

```
ps -e
```

OR for node process only use `ps -ef | grep node`
This will give you the list of all node process with id

to Kill all node process

```
sudo killall -9 node
```

Or for the specific id `sudo kill -9 id`

Answer (score 9):

I fixed the bug by changing the port which was

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);<br>
```

and changed to:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);<br>
```

Comment: How does this differ from applying what the accepted answer says to the answer given by Mark?

Answer (score 3):

The port Node is trying to use can be already used by another program. In my case it was [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/), which I had recently installed. I had to open http://localhost:3000/ in a browser to realize it. Another way to find the process is given [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/).

Answer (score 3):

**Reason for this error**

> Some other process is already running on the port  you have specified

**Simple and Quick solution**

On Linux OS, For example you have specified 3000 as the port

- Open the terminal and run `lsof -i :3000`. If any process is already running on  port 3000 then you will see this printing on the console

```js
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    16615 aegon   13u  IPv6 183768      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

- Copy the PID (process ID) from the output
- Run `sudo kill -9 16615` (you have to put PID after -9)
- Start the server again

Answer (score 2):

Close any other node servers that are running, even if they are in other terminal windows or running on different ports. That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the same port number then type `kill %` in the terminal, which kills the current background process and frees up the port for further usage.

Answer (score 2):

this means your file is running now. just enter below code and try again:

```
sudo pkill node
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually Ctrl+C keys not releasing port used by node process. So there is this error.
The resolution to the issue was using following code snippet in server.js:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  console.log( "\nGracefully shutting down from SIGINT (Ctrl-C)" );
  // some other closing procedures go here
  process.exit(1);
});
```

This worked for me.

You can also check for other solutions mentioned at [Graceful shutdown in NodeJS](https://hackernoon.com/graceful-shutdown-in-nodejs-2f8f59d1c357)

Comment: Best answer.Deserves way more up voting.

Answer (score 1):

If you've tried killing all node instances and other services listening on 3000 (the default used by the express skeleton setup) to no avail, you should check to make sure that your environment is not defining 'port' to be something unexpected. Otherwise, you'll likely get the same error. In the express skeleton's app.js file you'll notice line 15:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

In-order to fix this, terminate or close the server you are running.
If you are using Eclipse IDE, then follow this,

**Run > Debug**

[image]

Right-click the running process and click on **Terminate**.

Answer (score 1):

**events.js:183 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event**

I also got the same kind of problem and tried many ways but finally got this, this works well:

```
npm install ws@3.3.2 --save-dev --save-exact
```

Refer to this link for more clarifications https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2922

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today and the port was not used. The following approach helped:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install
npm start
```

Comment: Helped: looks like node modules have been corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've had to run `vagrant reload` as well. Even with no node processes running my express app in my virtual machine I was still getting this error until reloading the vagrant box.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the service that is using that port.

```
sudo service NAMEOFSERVICE stop
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was caused by forgetting to call `next()` in an expressjs `use' method call.

> If the current middleware does not end the request-response cycle, it must call next() to pass control to the next middleware, otherwise the request will be left hanging.

http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

http://www.codingdefined.com/2015/09/how-to-solve-nodejs-error-listen.html

Just change the port number from the Project properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the port from Gruntfile.js and run again.

Answer (score 0):

After killing the same process multiple times and not being able to locate what else was running on port 8000, I realized I was trying to run on port 8000 twice:

Before:

```
MongoClient.connect(db.url, (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  require('./app/routes')(app, database);

  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('We are live on ' + port);
  });
});

require('./app/routes')(app, {});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("We are live on " + port);
});
```

After:

```
MongoClient.connect(db.url, (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  require('./app/routes')(app, database);

  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('We are live on ' + port);
  });
});

require('./app/routes')(app, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found out, that a nodejs process that I had previously canceled with CTRL+C was still running. The problem in Windows 10 is, that [Ctrl + C Doesn't Kill Gracefully](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/16103) nodejs. I opened the task manager and killed the process manually. The solutions provided on GitHub didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you using windows, then you can end process from task manager for node.js

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me.

When I restarted my computer I could get the server up and running.

Mac
    `shutdown now -r`

Linux
    `sudo shutdown now -r`

Answer (score 0):

->check what’s running on port 8080 or what ever port u want to check

```
lsof -i @localhost:8080
```

if something is running u can close it or use some kill command to close it

Answer (score 0):

Simple just check your teminal in Visual Studio Code
Because me was running my node app and i hibernate my laptop then next morning i turn my laptop on back to development of software. THen i run the again command nodemon app.js
First waas running from night and the second was running my latest command so two command prompts are listening to same ports that's why you are getting this issue.
Simple Close one termianl or all terminal then run your node app.js or nodemon app.js

Answer (score 0):

The port you are listening to is already being listened by another process.

When I faced to this error I killed the process using Windows PowerShell (because I used Windows)

1. List itemopen the windows powershell
2. type `ps` and then you can get list of processes
3. find the process named **node**, and note the **Id**
4. type `Stop-process <Id>`
   I think that it is help for windows users

Answer (score 0):

IF it is in mac then it's all about IP of x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0. If you follow errors it would be something related to x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0. Add

**127.0.0.1       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0**

to **/etc/hosts** file. Then the problem is gone

Answer (score 0):

My answers is one of the solution

If you are trying to run angular application with below command

```
ng serve --open
```

--open Opens the url in default browser this tag is causing the issue. i don't know what is the purpose after angular 10 version which is not working. I am still analysing

Answer (score 0):

On windows :

**cmd 1 : lsof -i :<port no>**

This gives the process id

**cmd 2 : kill -9 <process id>**

done

Answer (score -1):

Just change your port,might be your current port is in use by iis or some other server.

Comment: This was asked and answered 4 years ago with the same but better answer.

Answer (score -1):

### Try the below fixes.

1. Try to close the process that is using your port.

   > **`netstat -tulnp | grep <port_number>`**
2. Installing the below pakcage fixed it for me forever.

   > **`npm install ws@3.3.2 --save-dev --save-exact`**
3. Run this command in your terminal :

   > **`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`**

   **For Arch Linux add this line to /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf:**

   `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288`

   Then execute:

   `sysctl --system`

   This will also persist across reboots.

   https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers#the-technical-details

Answer (score -1):

npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@2.1.