# Unhandled 'error' event while trying to run mean stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean.io

I follower every instruction for installing a MEAN stack application.

At the end of it all I run `grunt` and when I go to `http://localhost:3000` I get the following error:

```
Running "clean:0" (clean) task

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
>> 47 files lint free.

Running "csslint:src" (csslint) task
>> 5 files lint free.

Running "concurrent:tasks" (concurrent) task
Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
[nodemon] v1.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
debugger listening on port 5858
Mongoose: packages.findOne({ name: 'config' }) { fields: undefined }  
3000
Mean app started on port 3000 (development)
Mongoose: users.ensureIndex({ email: 1 }) { safe: undefined, background: true, unique: true }  
Mongoose: users.ensureIndex({ username: 1 }) { safe: undefined, background: true, unique: true }  
GET / 304 41.185 ms - -

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, open '/var/www/finnviz/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I searched and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17314748/463065), but this does not seem to be the case, when I run `ps aux | grep node` I dont get any running process:

```
trufa    14763  0.0  0.0  23492   956 pts/14   S+   15:39   0:00 grep --color=auto node
```

I searched through many answers but none seem to apply. Some suggest to [change the port](http://teknosains.com/i/solving-error-eventsjs72-throw-er-unhandled-error-event-in-nodejs). I tried it and the error is the same.

Any suggestions as to how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the automatic bower install does not work if you run npm with sudo.

1. I would recommend setting up `npm` so it does not require `sudo`.
2. Try running `$ bower install` from your project root, and then restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

you had run another server using the same port 8080.

Comment: Did you saw that the question was posted and answered 3 years ago ? And also that the logger selected an answer (relatively different from yours) ?